# How to retrieve images from json array usings alamofire image?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here is the piece of code i have used to get the images from url but the code crashes with the error posted below.Please someone help me to sort this.

```
let imageurl = Gift.imagesUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

Alamofire.request(imageurl, method: .get).responseImage { response in
    print(response)
}
```

ERROR:

```
 FAILURE: invalidURL("(    \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/ri1.jpg?1476104874\")")
```

Comment: `Gift.imagesUrl.replacingOccurrences(of:...)` Why? What is `Gift.imagesUrl` really? How did you get it? You need to properly parse and use it.

Comment: can you post how you are setting value for  Gift.imagesUrl

Comment: actually i am getting the response as: FAILURE: invalidURL("(\n    \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/ri1.jpg?1476104874\"\n)")... "/n" is included in the json response as an addon which is not present in the json.  Can you tell me how to retrieve the proper image url from server without "/n".

Comment: var _imagesUrl:String?                                                                             var imagesUrl:String {
        if _imagesUrl == nil {
            _imagesUrl = ""
        }
        return _imagesUrl!
    }                                                                                                                    if let image = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? NSArray {
           self._imagesUrl = String(describing: image)
        } ... **Gift is the model object class name**

Comment: `NSArray` in Swift 3+, no don't. Using `String(describing:someNSArray)`, no no and no. Use `self._imagesUrl = image.first`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please clarify what is Gift.imagesUrl. what do you want with it in Alamofre?

Comment: @Larme i am getting this error "FAILURE: invalidURL("(\n \"s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/…\"\n)")"

Comment: Parse correctly yourJSON, so edit your question with it and how you currently parse it

Comment: i got solution..........let urlstring  = Gift.imagesUrl
        let string = urlstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\n \" )(]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

Comment: Please self-answer your question instead of editing the question with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't let the solution being:

```
let string = urlstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\n \" )(]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

That's a hacky solution, not a viable one. It's a bad solution.

What is the real issue? The parsing to get the `imagesUrl` is wrong.

You did this:

```
var _imagesUrl:String? 
var imagesUrl:String 
{ 

    if _imagesUrl == nil 
    { 
        _imagesUrl = "" 
    } 
    return _imagesUrl! 
} 

if let image = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? NSArray 
{
    self._imagesUrl = String(describing: image) 
}
```

What's wrong?
Don't use `NSArray` in Swift3+. Use Swift Array. 
Don't use `String(describing:)`, that's not doing what you think it does. It's calling `description` method of the object (in your case an `NSArray`), that's why it added `(`, `\n`, `"`, `)`. You want the object, not the description.

Don't call your var `imagesUrl` with an "s" if it's only one, or you are only interested in the first one? That's unclear, and a misleading name.

It should be:

```
if let imageStringURLs = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? [String] { //Yes, use a Swift Array of String, not a NSArray
    self._imagesUrl = imageStringURLs.first //I took presumption that you are only interested in the first one, of not, then use an array to save them, not a String.
}
```

or:

```
var _imagesUrl: [String]?
var imagesUrl: [String]?
//if nil as you did
if let imageStringURLs = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? [String] { //Yes, use a Swift Array of String, not a NSArray
    self._imagesUrl = imageStringURLs
}
```

Then, you just do:

```
Alamofire.request(Gift.imagesUrl).responseImage{ response in
        print(response)
}
```

or (using the array)

```
let firstURL = Gift.imagesUrl[0] //Or if it's the second let secondURL = Gift.imagesUrl[1], etc.
Alamofire.request(firstURL).responseImage{ response in
        print(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
      let ImageURL = URL(string: "your image URL")!

      Alamofire.request(ImageURL).responseData { (response) in
         if response.error == nil {
            print(response.result)

           // Show the downloaded image:
             if let data = response.data {
                 self.downloadImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting **FAILURE: invalidURL("(\n    \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/ri1.jpg?1476104874\"\n)")**

Comment: i got solution.......let urlstring  = Gift.imagesUrl
        let string = urlstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\n \" )(]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

Answer (score 0):

```
let urlstring  = Gift.imagesUrl
    let string = urlstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\n \" )(]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

    Alamofire.request(string).responseImage{ response in
        print(response)
    }
```

Comment: That's a hacking solution. The real issue is about bad parsing. It's not a viable solution in final delivery.